# Return Varying Type from REST Endpoint

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, wcf-rest

I'm constructing a WCF REST service, with a single PUT operation.  The purpose is to update an account balance by adding or subtracting funds.  There are two primary responses the PUT operation can make:

- 200/OK.  An `AccountUpdate` object is serialized back to the caller, which contains the new account balance information.
- 409/Conflict.  A `AccountError` object is serialized back to the caller, which states the problem (usually an "account overdrawn" message).

The above is what the client expects for return values.  If this was ASP.NET Web API, this service would be easy to make.

However, with WCF REST I'm not sure how I am supposed to have two different return types for the same service operation.  Here is sample code:

```
    public AccountUpdate PutSomething([Safe] Funding funding)
    {
        if (HandleFunds(funding)){
          //**** Handle a 200 "OK" ****
          return new AccountUpdate(...);
        }else{
          //**** Handle a 409 "Conflict" ****
          OutgoingWebResponseContext response = WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse;
          response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Conflict;
          return new AccountError(...);
        }
    }
```

The above code won't compile, because `AccountError` is not polymorphic with `AccountUpdate`.

Is there a proper idiomatic way to handle this scenario with WCF REST?  Am I supposed to have my service operation simply return `object`?

One way I can solve this problem is to do a `throw new WebFaultException<AccountError>`, but that seems like an awkward way to handle an otherwise normal business flow.

Thoughts?

Comment: You might be interested in HttpResponseMessage.

Answer (score 0):

I would handle this by incorporating a Succeeded bit and ErrorMessage string in your AccountUpdate class. This class looks like it's used solely to *update* the account, and not to store account data.  Therefore returning an AccountUpdate object should also return the result of that update.  You could even have AccountUpdate contain a "Result" class with the data you want.